# Filling values from another dataframe based of value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

Hey I have dataframe like this

```
   Descriptions
1. i am going in car
2. He will go for match
3. D-1799
4. nothing better
5. SS-1428
6. going towards the office
7. GTY6QD12
```

and another Dataframe which has codes mentioned in above dataframne with the descriptions in next column.

```
   code           Description
1. D-1799      he is moving now
2. SS-1428     they will have some
3. GTY6QD12    is it well now
```

I want First Dataframe to be filled with the codes descriptions from 2nd Dataframe based on code. Required result should be like this.

```
   Descriptions
1. i am going in car
2. He will go for match
3. he is moving now
4. nothing better
5. they will have some
6. going towards the office
7. is it well now
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `Series` from `df2` created by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and selecting `Descriptions` column:

```
s = df2.set_index('code')['Description']
df1['Descriptions'] = df1['Descriptions'].replace(s)
print (df1)
               Descriptions
0         i am going in car
1      He will go for match
2          he is moving now
3            nothing better
4       they will have some
5  going towards the office
6            is it well now
```

If need substring replacement add `regex=True`:

```
df1['Descriptions'] = df1['Descriptions'].replace(s, regex=True)
```